# Request_Content in agentcontext empty when receiving a large XML

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have a java agent in IBM Domino which processes a XML content which is being received by HTTP POST. Now it seems that if the XML content is larger than aprox. 1180 lines, the agent is not processing the POST(XML) content. When I Perform a:

```
System.out.println(agentContext.getDocumentContext().getItemValueString("REQUEST_CONTENT"));
```

Then it returns empty.

Is there a maximum limit and if you could point me a workaround that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this technote](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21240370):

> If the POST data is less than 64 KB -  Use REQUEST_CONTENT to access
>   the POST data.
>
> If the POST data is greater than 64 KB -  Use REQUEST_CONTENT_000 to
>   access the first 6 4KB chunk, REQUEST_CONTENT_001 to access the second
>   64 KB chunk, REQUEST_CONTENT_002 to access the third 64 KB chunk, and
>   so on.
>
> A developer can use the NotesDocument.HasItem("REQUEST_CONTENT") call
>   to test for the presence of the REQUEST_CONTENT field. If it exists,
>   then there was less than 64 KB of POST data.

Answer (score 3):

I use something like this:

```
private String getRequestContent(Document document) throws Exception {
    String returnObject = "";

    try {
        if (document.hasItem("Request_Content")) {
            returnObject = document.getItemValueString("Request_Content");
        }
        else {
            if (document.hasItem("Request_Content_000")) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                    String fieldName = "Request_Content_" + String.format("%03d", i);
                    returnObject += document.getItemValueString(fieldName);
                }
            }
            else {
                throw new Exception("Request_Content fields not found");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("could not retrieve the Content from the Request", e);
    }

    return returnObject;

}
```